# How to show border but not make it re-sizable

Tags: c#, winforms

OK, this has probably been asked a thousand times, but everything says to use set `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`.  However when I do that I don't even get a border.  See Image1.  I am attempting to get what is seen in Image2, but I need the border to not show different cursors and to not make it re-sizable.  I'm on Windows 7, if that helps at all.

Image1:

[image: Image1]

Image2:

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

In general [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) states:
There are 4 fixed option.

**Fixed3D** A fixed, three-dimensional border.

**FixedDialog** A thick, fixed dialog-style border.

**FixedSingle** A fixed, single-line border.

**FixedToolWindow** A tool window border that is not resizable. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB. Although forms that specify FixedToolWindow typically are not shown in the taskbar, you must also ensure that the ShowInTaskbar property is set to false, since its default value is true.

I would try those.